# How can I pass a date to a UserControl in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm trying to send some data from my page to a usercontrol in UWP. It's a master/detail control on my ExpensesPage. I set a DataTemplate and then add that as my ItemTemplate and DetailsTemplate in xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" x:DataType="model:Category">
    <Grid Height="54" Padding="0,8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <FontIcon Grid.Column="0" FontSize="40" Glyph="{x:Bind SymbolAsChar}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CategoryName}" Style="{ThemeResource ListTitleStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CategorySummary}" Style="{ThemeResource ListSubTitleStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailsTemplate">
    <views:ExpensesDetailControl MasterMenuItem="{Binding}" FilterDate="{Binding FilterDateVariable, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>


<controls:MasterDetailsView
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="MasterDetailsViewControl"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Categories, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
    DetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}"
    NoSelectionContentTemplate="{StaticResource NoSelectionContentTemplate}"            
    BorderBrush="Transparent" />
```

In my ExpensesPage code behind I have it set like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
private DateTime _filterDate;
public DateTime FilterDateVariable
{
    get { return _filterDate; }
    set { Set(ref _filterDate, value); }
}
```

Then in my ExpensesDetailControl code behind I have this code:

```
public Category MasterMenuItem
{
    get { return GetValue(MasterMenuItemProperty) as Category; }
    set { SetValue(MasterMenuItemProperty, value); }
}

public DateTime FilterDate
{
    get { return DateTime.Parse(GetValue(FilterProperty).ToString()); }
    set { SetValue(FilterProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MasterMenuItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MasterMenuItem", typeof(Category), typeof(ExpensesDetailControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnMasterMenuItemPropertyChanged));

public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FilterDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(ExpensesDetailControl), new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Today, OnFilterPropertyChanged));

private static void OnMasterMenuItemPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as ExpensesDetailControl;
    control.ForegroundElement.ChangeView(0, 0, 1);
}

private static void OnFilterPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as ExpensesDetailControl;
    //should be able to filter the contents with the date here somehow!

}
```

The MasterMenuItem is triggered and works as expected but FilterDate does not.

I would expect the property to change when FilterDateVariable is changed but it doesn't seem to be going through to the ExpensesDetailControl. What am I doing wrong and how can I send my date through to my ExpensesDetailControl? I'm at a loss, even after reading a lot of other threads and information. This is kind of new to me. Thanks

Comment: Could you show more detail about your `Categories` in the code behind?

Comment: Hi, I've added more of the category code above now. Does it help? The Categories work just fine. I'm trying to pass a variable from my page command bar to the ExpensesDetailControl.

Comment: Both `MasterMenuItem` and `FilterDate` in the `DetailsTemplate` use the same `DataContext` (Categories). However the `FilterDateVariable` is not one of `Categories` property. So this binding is unavailable.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT OK, makes sense. So how do I pass FilterDateVariable to ExpensesDetailControl from my command bar on ExpensesPage?

Comment: Please try to add   `FilterDateVariable` property for `Categories` .And modify it in the command bar event.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT How can I add it to Categories when it is of type ObservableCollection<Category> ? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160679/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-mutley).